# How to populate an ArrayList of items to ListView through a custom adapter?

Tags: java, android, listview, arraylist

I have an ArrayList of items, each item contains 2 strings and 1 button. When I using List to store item, it worked well. After I changed to ArrayList to store items then it the emulator showed an empty screen.

MainAcativity:

```
    public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {


        public void mainlist(){
            ArrayList<ListItem> items = new ArrayList<ListItem>();
            for(int i = 0; i < items.size(); i++) {
                int num = i + 1;
                ListItem l = new ListItem("Item " + num, "sub item " + num);
                items.add(l);
            }
            ListView el=(ListView)findViewById(R.id.eventlist);
            MyArrayAdapter myArrayAdapter = new MyArrayAdapter(this, items);
            el.setAdapter(myArrayAdapter);
            myArrayAdapter.notifyDataSetChanged();
        }


        @Override
        protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
            super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
            setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
            mainlist();
        }
    }
```

Adapter:

```
    public class MyArrayAdapter extends ArrayAdapter<ListItem> {
        private ArrayList<ListItem> items;
        private Context context;

        public MyArrayAdapter(Context context, ArrayList<ListItem> items) {
            super(context, 0, items);
            this.items = items;
            this.context = context;
        }

        @Override
        public View getView(int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent){
            ListItem item = items.get(position);

            if(convertView==null) {
                convertView = LayoutInflater.from(context).inflate(R.layout.listitem, parent, false);
            }
            TextView itemView = (TextView)convertView.findViewById(R.id.item);
            TextView subItemView = (TextView)convertView.findViewById(R.id.sub_item);

            itemView.setText(item.getName());
            subItemView.setText(item.getDetail());

            return convertView;
        }
    }
```

Comment: Why not keep working with `List` interface if it works? Or even better migrate to a recycler view instead. [See here](https://developer.android.com/guide/topics/ui/layout/recyclerview)

Comment: Your code is almost exactly the same as in this codepath, except it is using `getItem` instead of a member list variable. I don't think that change should cause such an issue. Are you sure the objects are being assigned and read properly?
https://guides.codepath.com/android/Using-an-ArrayAdapter-with-ListView#using-a-custom-arrayadapter

Comment: I just changed to getItem to match the codepath, but it still didn't work :(

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
ArrayList<ListItem> items = new ArrayList<ListItem>();
  for(int i = 0; i < items.size(); i++) {
  int num = i + 1;
  ListItem l = new ListItem("Item " + num, "sub item " + num);
  items.add(l);
}
```

You are instantiating a new `ArrayList` which begins empty and then trying to iterate through the empty list and your for loop won't run.

Try the following if you just want a list of numbers:

```
ArrayList<ListItem> items = new ArrayList<ListItem>();
  for(int i = 0; i < 100; i++) {
  int num = i + 1;
  ListItem l = new ListItem("Item " + num, "sub item " + num);
  items.add(l);
}
```

Comment: OMG, such a tiny mistake....How could didn't I find that! It's working now, Cheers!

Answer (score 0):

Without data how can you generate list items.

```
ArrayList<ListItem> items = new ArrayList<ListItem>();
        for(int i = 0; i < items.size()/*size is 0,loop is not running*/; i++) {...
```

Insert some data like:

```
public void mainlist(){
        ArrayList<ListItem> items = new ArrayList<ListItem>();
        items.add(new ListItem("str1","str2"));
        ListView el=(ListView)findViewById(R.id.eventlist);
        MyArrayAdapter myArrayAdapter = new MyArrayAdapter(this, items);
        el.setAdapter(myArrayAdapter);
    }
```